# How to make a dynamic room layout accessible

Tags: html, reactjs, accessibility, wcag2.0

We are developing a React application that renders a dynamic room layout. This room layout represents a physical room with seats. Each room has an average of 40 seats, but there are rooms with 120 seats. Each seat has a popup that reveals more information and actions after clicking on the seat.

Currently, we are in the progress of making the application accessible. But we are not sure what the best practice is of navigating through the room layout.

The room layout can be navigated by using `tab` and `shift + tab`, but I can imagine that this can be annoying when there are 120 seats or so.

I think we can use the [ARIA: grid role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Grid_Role) implementation, but I'm not sure if this is the best practice.

[image: Example room layout]

Here is a [quick example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-carson-en6si?file=/src/App.js) of the layout.

Comment: Are the seats always in a square / rectangular pattern? And do the seats have to have numbers? I ask as if they are in a square / rectangle shape you might be better assigning a row(G) & column(3) system like a cinema. Are gaps as those seats are taken? `role="grid"` could be an option but I would suggest you simply supply an alternative that is as a standard `<table>` with each seat as a row & the columns containing the extra info etc. Depends on what the extra info is I suppose. Could you perhaps "spec" the system a little more, or better yet create a fiddle so we can see existing HTML, CSS

Comment: Thanks, Graham. The layout is 100% flexible and is not bound to a column/row system. I added gaps between the seats on purpose, but in most cases, the seats are grouped. An empty seat can only be identified by the seat number, but when a person occupies a seat, this changes to the person's full name. Sure, I can create a fiddle if that helps.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-carson-en6si?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `grid` role in your link is more appropriate, assuming that you want to layout the seats in a grid fashion.

Please read more here on the [Wai Aria Practices for the Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#grid) and [Layout Grids](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/grid/LayoutGrids.html) looks more appropriate to implement for your case.

Comment: Thanks! I've read those pages. I'm still not sure if this is the best option. Since the seats can be rendered in any order and with empty spaces between the rows and columns, I assume it will be hard to navigate through the layout in a grid fashion. I think pressing the ArrowDown key should focus the next seat following the seat numbers. This actually looks more like the listbox implementation. Would it also be valid to use a single column grid to achieve the same listbox navigation effect?

Comment: I saw your code sandbox and see it as grid. As far as you convey Seat Number information when seat is focused, it should be fine. I would assume rows having emptiness as in Seat 06 and Seat 29 in the form of col spans. I think you'll need to find out maximum number of seats that could be in a row and rest of the rows which doesn't have this maximum seats can be colspans.